# Cannot open Kazam file

Tags: 20.04, video, mp4, kazam

My PC cannot display the video, as an error informs that there isn't any app for doing so. The error message is this:

[image: Could not display video error]

> **Could not display "videoname.mp4"**
>
> There is no application installed for "MPEG-4 video" files. Do you want to search for an application to open this file?

So far it makes sense, because the problem appears when pressing on the button that is supposed to allow you to find an app for playing the video.

I suppose that this error has to do with the MP4 format, but I cannot solve it.

Any help?

Comment: Now have another problem related to the keyboard input @BeastOfCaerbannog

Comment: What kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that you don't have an application for playing MP4 files installed. Ubuntu 20.04 comes preinstalled with Totem, so you shouldn't have that problem. However, I suspect that you have either uninstalled it directly or got indirectly uninstalled along with other programs that you have removed.

So just install a media player. I recommend `mpv`, but you can install whichever you prefer. To install `mpv`, just run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install mpv
```

Then try to open your file. It should open just fine.